# Real Zoom in a plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, spy

I was wondering if there are a mean to zoom in the plot, I know about `spy` library (PGFPlots) but this later tries only to scale the windowed area and get the raster bitmap after a stretch. Here, I am talking about a real zoom like the way MATLAB figures/scopes do, and hence, with some depth of zooming, we arrive to a total discrete plot.

Comment: Thank you Jake for the link. The Qrrbrbirlbel's solution seems not be flexible especially for huge plots which require large memory size!

Comment: Could you edit your question to include an example where Qrrbrbirlbel's solution doesn't work for you?

Comment: The Qrrbrbirlbel's solution works fine for small to relative large plots. If you pay attention to the MWE you notice that the graph was plotted twice, such thing is impossible for me since my plots get huge and the TeX memory size limit will be easily overflew.

Comment: Tobi's solution doesn't have that problem.

Comment: I decide to emulate the local shape of the real signal. I found this method more easy and efficient.